# Quarkus: v.1.5.1 PgPool preparedQuery with parameters?

Tags: java, quarkus, mutiny

What is the right way to execute a prepared statement with parameters in Quarkus 1.5.1 version? As I see the `preparedQuery()` method of the `PgPool class` doesn't have a second `Tuple` argument as in the 1.4.2 version.

The definition in the smallpye-mutiny-vertx-sql-client-0.0.15.jar of Pool class is

```
public io.vertx.mutiny.sqlclient.PreparedQuery<io.vertx.mutiny.sqlclient.RowSet<io.vertx.mutiny.sqlclient.Row>> preparedQuery(String sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ahh I see, you can add the Tuple in the execute() method :)